# Python string concatenation of n coordinate grids

Tags: python, regex, string

I have N strings containing pixel values for X and Y coordinates, for example:

```
{ #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 }  
{ #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 }  
{ #020202 #020202 #030303 #020202 #010101 }  
{ #020202 #030303 #050505 #030303 #010101 }  
{ #020202 #030303 #0f0f0f #040404 #020202 }  
{ #030303 #0c0c0c #0f0f0f #0f0f0f #030303 }  
{ #040404 #0b0b0b #ffffff #ffffff #040404 }  
{ #0a0a0a #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #050505 }  
{ #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #040404 }  
{ #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #040404 }
```

And the second string

```
{ #040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #010101 }  
{ #040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #000000 }  
{ #050505 #020202 #010101 #010101 #000000 }  
{ #040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #000000 }  
{ #030303 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 }  
{ #020202 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 }  
{ #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 }  
{ #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 #000000 }  
{ #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 #000000 }  
{ #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 #000000 }
```

This represent a 10x10 `RGB` grid.

My problem is that i need to concatenate these two string to look like this for every row

```
{ #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #010101 } ...
```

This 10x10 grid was for split in two equal parts but there can be n-splits and therefore the string concatenation needs to be able to handle that.

Grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried thus far and what problem you ran into?

Comment: Nobody knows, how you store your strings and how the desired output is. Dictionary? List? Array? Individual variables? And why do you want to store RGB arrays as strings? Usually people prefer `numpy` arrays to vectorize  operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution returning the concatenated string:

```
A = "{ #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 } { #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 } { #020202 #020202 #030303 #020202 #010101 } { #020202 #030303 #050505 #030303 #010101 } { #020202 #030303 #0f0f0f #040404 #020202 } { #030303 #0c0c0c #0f0f0f #0f0f0f #030303 } { #040404 #0b0b0b #ffffff #ffffff #040404 } { #0a0a0a #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #050505 } { #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #040404 } { #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #040404 }"
B = "{ #040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #010101 } { #040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #000000 } { #050505 #020202 #010101 #010101 #000000 } { #040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #000000 } { #030303 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 } { #020202 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 } { #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 } { #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 #000000 } { #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 #000000 } { #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 #000000 }"

A = A[:-1].replace("{ ", "").replace("} ","|").split("|")
B = B[:-1].replace("{ ", "").replace("} ","|").split("|")
res = ["{ "+"".join(i) + "}" for i in list(zip(A,B))]
resString = "\n".join(r for r in res)
print(resString)
```

Output:

```
{ #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #010101 }
{ #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #000000 }
{ #020202 #020202 #030303 #020202 #010101 #050505 #020202 #010101 #010101 #000000 }
{ #020202 #030303 #050505 #030303 #010101 #040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #000000 }
{ #020202 #030303 #0f0f0f #040404 #020202 #030303 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 }
{ #030303 #0c0c0c #0f0f0f #0f0f0f #030303 #020202 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 }
{ #040404 #0b0b0b #ffffff #ffffff #040404 #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 }
{ #0a0a0a #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #050505 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 #000000 }
{ #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #040404 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 #000000 }
{ #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #040404 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 #000000 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = "{ #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 } { #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 } { #020202 #020202 #030303 #020202 #010101 } { #020202 #030303 #050505 #030303 #010101 } { #020202 #030303 #0f0f0f #040404 #020202 } { #030303 #0c0c0c #0f0f0f #0f0f0f #030303 } { #040404 #0b0b0b #ffffff #ffffff #040404 } { #0a0a0a #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #050505 } { #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #040404 } { #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #040404 }"
B = "{ #040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #010101 } { #040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #000000 } { #050505 #020202 #010101 #010101 #000000 } { #040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #000000 } { #030303 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 } { #020202 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 } { #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 } { #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 #000000 } { #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 #000000 } { #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 #000000 }"

A = A.split("} {")
B = B.split("} {")

AB = zip(A,B)
res = ["{"+"".join(i).replace("{", "").replace("}", "")+"}" for i in AB]
print res

Result:
['{ #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101  #040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #010101 }', '{ #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101  #040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #000000 }', '{ #020202 #020202 #030303 #020202 #010101  #050505 #020202 #010101 #010101 #000000 }', '{ #020202 #030303 #050505 #030303 #010101  #040404 #020202 #010101 #010101 #000000 }', '{ #020202 #030303 #0f0f0f #040404 #020202  #030303 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 }', '{ #030303 #0c0c0c #0f0f0f #0f0f0f #030303  #020202 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 }', '{ #040404 #0b0b0b #ffffff #ffffff #040404  #010101 #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 }', '{ #0a0a0a #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #050505  #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 #000000 }', '{ #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #040404  #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 #000000 }', '{ #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #ffffff #040404  #010101 #010101 #010101 #000000 #000000 }']
```